# Is atomic.load() is faster than calling it normal

Tags: c++, performance, atomic, stdatomic

Recently I have been using atomic numbers alot in c++ as i use threading too much and thread safe is important to me

Well, I had a problem with printf() function here is an example

```
atomic_uint64_t count = {0}

printf("%lu",count);

// It gives error couple of errors like  atomic(cost atomic&) = delete; and use of deleted function atomic so i had to write it like this to make it work

printf("%lu",count.load());

// Or

printf("%lu",(uint64_t)count);
```

Well anyways i don't which is better for performance i really care about the speed

So i started to thinking about which is better to retrieve the value and use it in if conditions or anywhere else

Like

```
if(count.load() < 8 ){

// Do smth
}
```

or

```
if(count < 8){
// Do smth
}
```

Which is better for speed and performance and thanks.

Comment: They're exactly identical in their meaning (unless you pass a non-default memory order like `count.load(std::memory_order_acquire)`).  I'd expect there to be no difference in the generated assembly for all compilers across all ISAs, with optimization enabled of course.

Comment: Note that `if(count < 8)` is relying on the fact that `std::atomic<uint64_t>` has an `operator uint64_t`, and also [that operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T) is equivalent to calling `load` on it.

Comment: Since performance is key, you should (if you haven't already), put up a framwork of measuring performance. Refuse any commit that degrades performance below a set threshold.

Answer (score 2):

**They're exactly identical in their meaning** (unless you pass a non-default memory order like `count.load(std::memory_order_acquire)`).

**I'd expect there to be no difference in the generated assembly for all compilers across all ISAs, with optimization enabled of course.**  There isn't for GCC/clang/MSVC/ICC in code I've looked at on https://godbolt.org/.  This is true regardless of surrounding code it's inlining into.

If there is ever a difference, and one is slower or takes more code-size, report that as a missed-optimization compiler bug in whatever compiler you're using.  (Unless you had optimization disabled, then an extra level of calls to wrapper functions is possible.)

---

As for the error, that's because you're evaluating it in a context that doesn't already imply a type: as an operand for a variadic function (`printf`).

If there's enough context to imply that you want the underlying T value from an `atomic<T>` (which is what `atomic_uint64_t` is), then the `operator T()` overload is called, which is [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T) as being equivalent to `.load()`.  Same deal for assignment and `.store()`.

There aren't any other functions that let you access only the low 32 bits of an atomic 64-bit integer (unfortunately); even on a 32-bit machine, current compilers will actually go to the trouble of doing a 64-bit atomic load (which is efficient on some 32-bit machines, not on others), then discarding the high 32 if you cast the value to a narrower type. (This is a missed-optimization, but compilers truly don't optimize atomics for the moment.)

So there's no ambiguity being resolved by `.load`, or any way a cast can pick a different load.

---

One reason for the existence of `.load()` and `.store()` is that they take a `std::memory_order` parameter, which is defaulted to `seq_cst` but can be weaker if you just need atomicity but only acq/rel synchronization between threads.  Or none at all with `relaxed`, *just* atomicity.

Another reason is to let you write `foo.load()` to remind readers of you code that this is an atomic variable, not just a plain primitive type.  For that style reason I'd prefer `count.load()`.  Presumably if you changed its type away from `uint64_t`, you'd want to change how you printed it, not still cast it to `uint64_t`.  Using `.load()` will let the compiler warn you about the format-string mismatch if you change its type.